# What are the benefits of types being first-class objects?

Tags: language-agnostic, types, language-design, abstraction, first-class

Does anybody here have good examples where types as first-class objects come in hand?

I guess it helps to straightforwardly implement some math concepts, indeed that is the kind of examples I'm looking for.

**UPD** To clarify the question, what can be done if one can make functions accepting types and returning types, or store types in variables?

I'm studying [Aldor](http://www.aldor.org/), though due to license issue it is a bit dead. There types are said to be first-class objects, at least in the sence above.

Comment: "Does anybody here have good examples where types as first-class objects come in hand?" -- Do you have any examples, even if it's a "bad" one? I guess it's not quite clear to me, what *exactly* you mean by "types as first-class objects". Are you talking about compile-time reflective metaprogramming à la Template Haskell or C++, parametric polymprhism à la Haskell / Java Generics / .NET Generics, higher-kinded parametric polymorphism (type constructor polymorphism) à la Haskell / Scala, some kind of runtime reflection over types, or something else entirely?

Comment: +1, BTW, regardless of my earlier comment. This looks to be a super-interesting question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Agda2, ats-lang.org and other languages with dependent types. Not quite what you asked, but related.

Comment: Yes, I've already seen it. And indeed it is rather close to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Reflection**

If types are first-class objects is that you can do [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29#Implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic factory.

```
_types = {}

register_type(typ, iden):
  _types[iden] = typ

def factory(iden):
  typ = _types.get(iden)
  if not typ:
    raise ValueError('Type not registered for %r' % iden)
  return typ()

register_type(SomeClass, 'class1')
register_type(SomeOtherClass, 'class2')

print factory('class1')
```

Comment: You can register and unregister classes in the factory as desired, instead of relying on a if or switch structure to select from a fixed set of classes.